# boilerplatejs and permissions

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, boilerplatejs

First thing first, Boilerplatejs looks really impressive and promising!
Just started to learning it, looking forwarder for some architecture documentation and more tutorials.

question:
Does boilerplatejs implements some permissions mechanism for displaying and managing widgets in large application?
for instance a particular user X can operate on module A but not on B (though he see it on screen), while user Y does not see module B at all but can see and operate module A for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no authorization mechanism built in to BoilerplateJS, and you will have to custom build according to your requirements. Remember client side authorization is not really sufficient, it should be enforced on server side as well to ensure security.

BTW, you can see how we handled authentication (not authorization) in some applications here: [BoilerplateJS: recommended way to handle authorization and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545476/boilerplatejs-recommended-way-to-handle-authorization-and-authentication)